# How can I map inherited model to entity using Scala and Squeryl?

Tags: scala, inheritance, database-design, squeryl

I have the model **User** on my system that has a OneToMany relationship with **Role**, role is currently a trait and I have other roles inherinting from it: AdministratorRole, VisitorRole, ResidentRole. My doubt is how can I model (best way) this system to my entities database. Below my current "Role" models:

*PS: Ignore the //**TODOS***

```
trait Role extends KeyedEntity[Long]
{
  val id:Long = 0
  val identifier = ""
  val idMetaData:Long =  0
  //val permissions = List[Permission]()
}

class AdministratorRole(val idCondo:Long) extends Role {
      override val identifier = "AdministratorRole"
      //TODO Map relationships
      lazy val fromCondo:Condo = null

}

class ResidentRole(override val id:Long, val idUnit:Long) extends Role{
  override val identifier = "ResidentRole"
  //TODO Map relationships
  lazy val fromHousingUnit:HousingUnit =  null
}

class VisitorRole(val idFromUser:Long) extends Role {
  override val identifier = "VisitorRole"
  //TODO Map relationships
  lazy val fromUser =  null

}
```

And here my current "Role" entities:

```
create table Roles(
    id int primary key,
    identifier varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    idUser int NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(id)
);

create table AdministratorRoles(
    idRole int NOT NULL UNIQUE  REFERENCES Roles(id),
    idCondo int NOT NULL REFERENCES Condos(id)
);

create table ResidentRoles(
    idRole int NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES Roles(id),
    idUnit int NOT NULL REFERENCES Units(id)
);

create table VisitorRoles(
    idRole int NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES Roles(id),
    idFromUser int NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(id)
);
```

How can I map these models/entities? I'm really having a hard time. Since now, thanks for the help.

Comment: This is a database modelling question, not a Scala question. Essentially what you need are three tables: a user table, a role_type table, a mapping table that maps a user to a role_type.

Comment: I don't know if Trait is the better solution too on this case. So this is why I tagged Scala.

Comment: The use of `trait` here is fine, actually recommended.